# How can I extract, edit and replot a data matrix in Abaqus?

Tags: matrix, transformation, contour, abaqus, stress

Good afternoon,

We´ve been working on an animal model (skull) applying a series of forces and evaluating the resultant stresses in Abaqus. We got some of those *beautiful and colourful* (blue-to-red) contour-plots. Now, we´d like to obtain a similar image but coloured by a new matrix, which will be the result of some methematical transformations.

So, how can I extract the data matrix used to set those colour patterns (I guess with X-, Y-, Z-, and von Mises-values or so), apply my transformation, and **replot the data to get a new** (comparable) **figure with the new values**?

Thanks a lot and have a great day!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please mark the answer as 'accepted' if it answers your question or add comments otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it myself but I know that this is possible. You can start with the documentation (e.g. [here](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAECAERefMap/simacae-t-rescreatebtn.htm) and [here](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAECAERefMap/simacae-c-resvalidexpression.htm)).

After experimenting using GUI you can check out the corresponding python code which should be automatically recorded in the abaqus.rpy file at your working directory (or at C:\temp). Working it trhough you could get something like:

```py
myodb = session.openOdb('my_fem.odb') # or alternatively `session.odbs['my_fem.odb']` if it is already loaded into the session

# Define a temporary step for accessing your transformed output
tempStep = myodb.Step(name='TempStep', description='', domain=TIME, timePeriod=1.0)

# Define a temporary frame to storeyour transformed output
tempFrame = tempStep.Frame(frameId=0, frameValue=0.0, description='TempFrame')

# Define a new field output
s1f2_S = myodb.steps['Step-1'].frames[2].fieldOutputs['S'] # Stress tensor at the second frame of the 'Step-1' step
s1f1_S = myodb.steps['Step-1'].frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'] # Stress tensor at the first frame of the 'Step-1' step
tmpField = s1f2_S - s1f1_S

userField = tempFrame.FieldOutput(
    name='Field-1', description='s1f2_S - s1f1_S', field=tmpField
)
```

Now, to display your new Field Output using python you can do the following:

```py
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.setFrame(
    step='TempStep', frame=0
)
```

For more information on used methods and objects, you can consult with the documentation "Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide":

- `Step()`: Odb commands -> OdbStep object -> Step();
- `Frame()`: Odb commands -> OdbFrame object -> Frame();
- `FieldOutput object`: Odb commands -> FieldOutput object;